# How can I access the lambda execution context from within a Quarkus REST API?

Tags: aws-lambda, jax-rs, quarkus

A regular Lambda handler has it, but in the Quarkus generated JAX-RS handler I cannot find a way to access it. I assume there should be a way to inject it or something... Why I'm asking? I would like to read the lambda execution ID to pass it back, so I can check when this particular execution has ended - without the extra work of creating extra resources (including step functions) or database flags.

Comment: I think you can use https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http and about executionID without lambda you can use https://quarkus.io/guides/opentracing

Comment: @özkanpakdil the amazon-lambda-http is exactly the problem: it doesn't expose (directly?) the context. And I'm using lambda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which context you want and which dependency / API Gateway you use.

For lambda context you can use:

```java
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    public String ctx(@Context com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context ctx) { }

}
```

See: https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http#injectable-aws-context-variables

Comment: Indeed, this was not yet available at the time the question was asked.